# animating multiple text using react

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm trying to fade in and fade out multiple texts using jquery in react but I'm getting the error that `Line 46:6:  'jquery' is not defined  no-undef` even though I did `npm i jquery --save`. How do I run this small piece of jquery code with react or is there any library through which I can achieve a similar effect?

this is the effect that I was trying to add into the react project -> [codepen](https://codepen.io/AmruthPillai/pen/axvqB)

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import $ from "jquery";
import "./App.css";
export const App = () => {
  (function ($) {
    $.fn.extend({
      rotaterator: function (options) {
        var defaults = {
          fadeSpeed: 900,
          pauseSpeed: 900,
          child: null,
        };

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function () {
          var o = options;
          var obj = $(this);
          var items = $(obj.children(), obj);
          items.each(function () {
            $(this).hide();
          });
          if (!o.child) {
            var next = $(obj).children(":first");
          } else {
            var next = o.child;
          }
          $(next).fadeIn(o.fadeSpeed, function () {
            $(next)
              .delay(o.pauseSpeed)
              .fadeOut(o.fadeSpeed, function () {
                var next = $(this).next();
                if (next.length == 0) {
                  next = $(obj).children(":first");
                }
                $(obj).rotaterator({
                  child: next,
                  fadeSpeed: o.fadeSpeed,
                  pauseSpeed: o.pauseSpeed,
                });
              });
          });
        });
      },
    });
  })(jquery);

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#rotate").rotaterator({ fadeSpeed: 900, pauseSpeed: 200 });
  });
  return (
 <div className="awards">
        <div className="awardHead">Awards</div>
        <img
          src="./images/trophy.jpg"
          width="300px"
          alt=""
          className="awardPhoto"
        />
        <div id="rotate">
          <div>
            <h2 className="smallAwardHead">BEST Company</h2>
            <p>hello</p>
          </div>
          <div>
           <h2 className="smallAwardHead">BEST Company</h2>
            <p>hello</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h2 className="smallAwardHead">BEST Company</h2>
            <p>hello</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h2 className="smallAwardHead">BEST Company</h2>
            <p>hello</p>
          </div>

          <div>
            <h2 className="smallAwardHead">BEST Company</h2>
            <p>hello</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You import jQuery as `$` but then reference it as `jquery` at line 46 of your code, despite the fact that you've neither declared nor defined a variable named `jquery`  Just pass the `$` instead:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import $ from "jquery";
import "./App.css";
export const App = () => {
  (function ($) {
    $.fn.extend({
      rotaterator: function (options) {
        var defaults = {
          fadeSpeed: 900,
          pauseSpeed: 900,
          child: null,
        };

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function () {
          var o = options;
          var obj = $(this);
          var items = $(obj.children(), obj);
          items.each(function () {
            $(this).hide();
          });
          if (!o.child) {
            var next = $(obj).children(":first");
          } else {
            var next = o.child;
          }
          $(next).fadeIn(o.fadeSpeed, function () {
            $(next)
              .delay(o.pauseSpeed)
              .fadeOut(o.fadeSpeed, function () {
                var next = $(this).next();
                if (next.length == 0) {
                  next = $(obj).children(":first");
                }
                $(obj).rotaterator({
                  child: next,
                  fadeSpeed: o.fadeSpeed,
                  pauseSpeed: o.pauseSpeed,
                });
              });
          });
        });
      },
    });
  })($); // <== this here was previously an undeclared var of `jquery`

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#rotate").rotaterator({ fadeSpeed: 900, pauseSpeed: 200 });
  });
  return (
 <div className="awards">
        <div className="awardHead">Awards</div>
        <img
          src="./images/trophy.jpg"
          width="300px"
          alt=""
          className="awardPhoto"
        />
        <div id="rotate">
          <div>
            <h2 className="smallAwardHead">BEST Company</h2>
            <p>hello</p>
          </div>
          <div>
           <h2 className="smallAwardHead">BEST Company</h2>
            <p>hello</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h2 className="smallAwardHead">BEST Company</h2>
            <p>hello</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h2 className="smallAwardHead">BEST Company</h2>
            <p>hello</p>
          </div>

          <div>
            <h2 className="smallAwardHead">BEST Company</h2>
            <p>hello</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
);
};
```

Comment: thanks. it got solved. also I'm kinda new to react, so I was having doubts as to why I can't see any image even though I declared it as `<img src="./images/eclipse.png" id="header-img" alt=""/>`

Comment: @reduxHelpPlz - no problem.  Just a word of warning-- generally speaking, usage of jQuery (and really any direct, imperative DOM manipulation) is considered an antipattern in the React and wider MV* web framework world.  Ideally you instead use components and interact with their lifecycle to achieve your desired affects.  If you find yourself leaning heavily on jQuery, you're likely going to find yourself having a really unpleasant time with maintenance and/or debugging at some point.  Good luck!